# Accessing Private Nested class member of base class outside base class

Tags: c++, inner-classes

I have a base class and nested class with structure given below.

Base Hpp file

```
class Base{
private:
class Nested;
Nested* nested_ptr;
public:
Base();
Nested& GetNested();
```

Base Cpp file

```
Base::Base(){
nested_ptr = new Nested();
}
Base::Nested& Base::GetNested(){
return *nested_ptr;
}
```

The nested class is implemented in a separate file.

My compiler is apple clang 11.0 and cpp standard is 17.

When I try to access nested class via

```
Base base{}
Base::Nested& nested = base.GetNested();
```

I am getting compiler error.
But when i try to access nested via

```
Base base{}
auto& nested = base.GetNested();
```

This compiles successfully. Is this feature portable or is it a bug in apple clang compiler.

```
Base base{};
base.GetNested().DoSomething();
```

This also compiles successfully.

Comment: Basically, `private` is only concerned with names. As long as you don't use the name (like when using `auto` or chaining calls), it's not violated.